# Extend all child elements to max available width in a div with scroll

Tags: html, css

Parent element has fixed width and overflow:auto to display a scrollbar. There are several child elements inside the parent that have wider content that others, but I need to expand the width of all elements to fill the parent. For example, one div needs to expand because it has background color and when user scrolls the parent div, the background color gets capped at the width of initial viewport.

Here is jsfiddle to illustrate example.
https://jsfiddle.net/jpsvwdm3/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child
  </div>
  <div class="long_child">
    long child
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #bbb;
}
.child {
  background: lightyellow;
  padding: 5px;
}
.long_child {
  width: 500px;
  background: wheat;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I can not follow what you are trying to do, maybe this? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: When you saying `max available width` do you mean that the `.child` will be the same width like the `.long_child` but the `.parent''s width will stay 300px?

Comment: I mean that .child should be the same length as .long_child. Parent is fixed to 300px and has a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care to use jQuery here maybe a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqwqf159/1/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqwqf159/1/)

```
var maxWidth = 0;
$('.parent div').each(function () {
  maxWidth = ($(this).width() > maxWidth) ? $(this).width() : maxWidth;
});
$('.parent div').each(function () {
  $(this).width(maxWidth);
});
```